# USB bus ports representation in sysfs

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, embedded-linux, libusb, sysfs

Following is the output of /sys/bus/usb/devices/ in the embedded system.

```
# ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/
1-0:1.0    1-1        1-1.1      1-1.1:1.0  1-1.1:1.1  1-1.1:1.2  1-1:1.0    usb1
#
```

While trying to understand this output, it was mentioned in some place as `"bus-port.port"`.

My understanding is a port will be connected to a bus and device will connect to port, my doubt here is how a port is connected to another port.
In which scenario the Kernel will create sysfs entry as `"1-1.1"`.

Comment: **.1** is USB interface on the above connection.

Comment: If `.1` is USB interface in `"1-1.1"` then left with `"1-1"` in which `-1` should be configuration and `1-` should be port. In this there is no bus representation.
As per "https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-bus-usb" it should be `bus(1)-port(1).port(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when a docking station is connected.

In your example, `1-1` is a device connected to port 1 on your computer and `1-1.1` is a device connected to port 1 on a docking station that is connected to port 1 on your computer.